# Viewstate: 2 different formats?

Tags: html, asp.net, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a webpage, I hit the necessity to work with ASP.NET's `__VIEWSTATE` variables. So, ever the optimist, I decided to read up on those variables, and their formats. Even though classified as Open Source by Microsoft, I couldn't find any formal definition:

Everybody agrees the first step to do is decode the string, using a `Base64` decoder. Great - that works...

Next - and this is where the confusion sets in:

1. Roughly 3/4 of the decoders seem to use binary values (characters whose values indicate the the type of field which is follow). Here's an [example of such a specification](https://deadliestwebattacks.com/2011/05/13/a-spirited-peek-into-viewstate-part-i/). This format also seems to expect a 'signature' of `0xFF 0x01` as first two bytes.
2. The rest of the articles (such as [this one](http://aspalliance.com/135_ViewState_All_You_Wanted_to_Know)) describe a format where the fields in the format are separated (or marked) by `t< ... >`, `p< ... >`, etc. (this seems to be the case of the page I'm interested in).

Even after looking at over a hundred pages, I didn't find any mention about the existence of two formats.

My questions are: Are there two different formats of `__VIEWSTATE` variables in use, or am I missing something basic? Is there any formal description of the `__VIEWSTATE` contents somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> The view state is serialized and deserialized by the
>   System.Web.UI.LosFormatter class—the LOS stands for limited object
>   serialization—and is designed to efficiently serialize certain types
>   of objects into a base-64 encoded string. The LosFormatter can
>   serialize any type of object that can be serialized by the
>   BinaryFormatter class, but is built to efficiently serialize objects
>   of the following types:
>
> - Strings
> - Integers
> - Booleans
> - Arrays
> - ArrayLists
> - Hashtables
> - Pairs
> - Triplets

Everything you need to know about ViewState: [Understanding View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Diego. I knew about that reference. My problem is that there seem to be two formats for the viewstate *internally*. And that reference does not seem to describe the low level aspects.